# AngularJS models explanation

Tags: angularjs, model, factory

I am utter confused as to what a model is in angularjs. In asp.net mvc, my understanding of the model is the class that defines the domain object, kind of like a DTO:

```
public class Person {
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Very light weight. My business logic, on the other hand, is not contained here but instead in a repository, which in turn has an interface. The controller requests data via an interface to the repository. The repository filters and retrieves the data, then passes it to the controller. I guess one could probably argue that the repository, interface, and DTO together make up the model.

Based on my understanding then, an angular model, at least in instances where it is retrieving, manipulating, and passing data to the controller, would be a factory/service. Is that correct?

Comment: No. Model is data, variables and methods in controller scope used to drive the view. Controller can be wired to a service/factory to access the data and methods but those services won't affect view without being bound to controller model (scope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angularjs, the model is the $scope variable. I am not aware of the MVC in ASP.NET, but seeing your example I feel that as a comparison we can say that the person class resides inside the $scope.

Also from your question, in ASP.NET, business logic seems to be not in the controller. Not sure what is the role of controller is in ASP.NET, but in AngularJS, it is where the business logic is.

May be the diagram in [this AngularJS Concepts page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#controller) might make you more clearer.

[image]

Comment: I like that you provided a link to angular docs. Thanks. From what I read in it controllers DO contain business logic, but sometimes that business logic is better abstracted away into a service or factory. I appears you and charlietfl seem to agree since $scope contains data. Therefore, your model really can't contain business logic, that would exist in your controllers and services. Is that correct?

Comment: As for ASP.net MVC, the controller requests data via the service/repository, which puts it in a domain object and passes it back to the controller, The controller then passes it to the view.

Comment: Yup exactly. Model ($scope) contains only the data. And the business logic exists in controllers and services (which I guess is used in controllers anyway).

Comment: @steveareeno Hmm.. I see, In Angular, the data is made available in the Controller by Angular itself. Also the data and view have a two-way data binding, in a sense, controller can just change the data ($scope) and is automatically updated in view :)

Comment: sweet. I like this explanation. thanks for your help!